# Fixed Positioning of elements?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I was wondering how to make an element with a fixed position change it's height or rather it's styling once it hit a certain point on the webpage. Let me explain, here are a few examples from sites that perform this event. I'm really just wondering how it happens and the work about to doing this?

http://www.animecenter.tv/
https://www.yahoo.com/

I've tried many methods, but either I'm doing something wrong or the solution is actually pretty easy and I'm over thinking it.

html:

```
<header>
    <div id="Logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <a href="#"><div class="alter-ref">exa</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="alter-ref">exa</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="alter-ref">exa</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="alter-ref">exa</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="alter-ref">exa</div></a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

css:

```
header {    
  background-color:#247BC1;     
  width:100%;   
  height:80px;  
  border-bottom:1px solid #005fad;  
  position:fixed;   
  top:0;    
  left:0; 
}
```

I've tried but, clearly it is not the effect I want that the websites listed above showcase:

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
 $(window).scroll(function(){             
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {                 
     $('.scrollup').fadeIn();             
   } 
   else {                 
     $('.scrollup').fadeOut();             
   }         
 });            

 $('.scrollup').click(function(){             
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);             
   return false;         
 });       
});
```

(added by Erik Philips)](http://jsfiddle.net/TL927/2/)

Comment: Can you show your attempts? It will help us better spot where you lack understanding/knowledge to do such a thing.

Comment: Please do not add code to comments.  You can update your question as many times as needed to get your question answered.

Comment: Oh sorry I'm sort of new to this site.

Comment: Please take a minute to review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As you question currently stands there is no way to debug your code (missing html).  I'd suggest adding your html, and to get your answer faster, create a MCVE at [jsfiddle.net (completely optional)](http://jsfiddle.net/TL927/1/).

Comment: Where is your `scrollup` class in HTML? Clearly the javascript will do nothing if the class being targeted doesn't exist.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions.

Comment: Here is a really simple script based on yours that does a variety of things on a central div http://jsfiddle.net/TL927/7/. To do something like you note on the links, you just have to identify the element you want to change, and apply an appropriate style

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to use a jquery plugin like [ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) which enables you to pin elements when scrolled to a certain point on the webpage.

You can also simply have two separate codes, one for the fixed element, and one for the initial not fixed element, and then switch the codes when the user scrolls to a certain point by toggling

```
display:none
```

and

```
display:block.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really useful solution to the problem.

Comment: this does address the overall problem, but not the issue with @Draginto's code